# Laravel eloquent unguarded during seeding

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-artisan

I am experiencing a strange problem with eloquent.

I've got two eloquent models, a User model and a Profile model which both have separate tables and have a one to one relationship.

I have a single form where the data for both of these models is passed into. So data belonging to User and Profile is present in the form.

I tried to perform the inserts as cleanly as possible from the controller:

```
$user = $this->users->createUser($request->all());
```

the `createUser` function is defined like this

```
public function createUser(array $data)
{
    $user = new User($data);
    // set some non relevant user options here...
    $user->save();

    $profile = new Profile($data);
    $user->profile()->save($profile);

    return $user;
}
```

But this produces a sql error, because eloquent assigns all the values from the form to both models, so User and Profile both get all the same properties, so eloquent tries to insert into columns that don't exist for the given model.

I thought that the `$fillable` field was used to prevent this sort of thing from happening, but I do have the `$fillable` fields defined in both models:

```
// User
protected $fillable = ['email', 'password', ...];

// Profile
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', ...];
```

I've also tried this: `(new User)->fill($data)` but that doesn't work, nor should it since the `fill` method is also called from the `Model` constructor.

In my mind this is not the expected behaviour, but then again, I may have misunderstood the concept of fillable. Any insight would be appreciated. I know this can be solved by declaring each key I want to send to the constructor, but that seems very messy to me. Also, I am using laravel v5.2.29

**EDIT**

Upon further testing I've come to the conclusion that this only happens inside when I run the database seeders, where I do use these functions. Digging deeper, I see that this makes perfect sense, since running the seed command "unguards" the base Model class. So this is expected behaviour.

My question is, is there any way to override this default, so that the models don't get "unguarded" when running the seed command, so that I can use my helper functions to populate my test database, or do I have to correctly define each data record manually inside the seeder classes?

Comment: Do you have constructor in your Model ? You are passing User and Profile an array make sure a constructor is there for handling it.

Comment: Both the User and Profile inherit from the base Model class, and I'm not overriding the constructor. I've narrowed down the problem (see my edit) but am unsure of how to get around this in a clean way.

Comment: why not go to phpmyadmin or whatever and insert data there ?

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of the seeders in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, from some version of Laravel 5.2 when using seeding models are unguarded as you noticed. In fact it's quite reasonable it's unguarded, but if you want to change it, well it's possible but not so simple.

Here are steps you should do to achieve that:

1. Comment in `config/app.php` line `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class`, add add line with your custom `ConsoleSupportServiceProvider` class.
2. Create this class same as original `ConsoleSupportServiceProvider` (actually you can extend it) but in `$providers` property change `Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider` into custom one
3. Again create custom `SeedServiceProvider` that extends original `SeedServiceProvider` and now override `registerSeedCommand` to create again custom `SeedCommand` class
4. Create custom `SeedCommand` class that extends original `SeedCommand`  and now all you need is changing:

   ```
   public function fire()
   {
       if (! $this->confirmToProceed()) {
         return;
      }

      $this->resolver->setDefaultConnection($this->getDatabase());

      Model::unguarded(function () {
         $this->getSeeder()->run();
      });
   }
   ```

   into

   ```
   public function fire()
   {
       if (! $this->confirmToProceed()) {
         return;
      }

      $this->resolver->setDefaultConnection($this->getDatabase());

      $this->getSeeder()->run();

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It does make sense that the database should be unguarded during the seeding process, so in the end I changed my seeds. I did try to implement my own Seed command, but it didn't work, and now I understand why - I didn't change any service providers. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `$unguarded` variable is preserved once you add it to your Model class manually. Works with Laravel 9.x

```
protected static $unguarded = false;
```

In the context:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected static $unguarded = false;  // add this line to your code
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];

    public function vouchers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Voucher::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why digging this up ?

Comment: Thanks for asking. It just happened to me so I wanted to share my solution. Maybe you have a better understanding / solution?

Comment: Your solution is unrelated to the OP issue and it's been 6 years. The real issue here was that the OP was passing unrelated data to save function, the fact that seeders are unguarded by default is not an issue.

Comment: And also overriding unguarded for the whole project is a bad idea, use Order::reguard() instead, to reguard only on your seeder

Comment: Gotcha. Works for me, thanks! Maybe I'd remove this post, what do you think?

Comment: Well you can keep it there, perhaps it will be usefull